# Proof of arithmetic mean being unbiased estimator

Tags: probability, expected-value

I need to understand the proof that $m=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n X_k$ is an unbiased estimator of the arithmetic mean $p$. Now I am doing this for the statistical model $(\{0,1\}^n,\mathscr{P}(\{0,1\}^n),(\text{Ber}(p)^{\otimes n})_{p \in [0,1]})$.  It is $x\in \{0,1\}^n$ and $X_k(x)=x_k$ the "answer of the k-th person".

The proof goes:
$$
\mathbb{E}_p(m)= \mathbb{E}_p\left(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n X_k\right)=\frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^n \mathbb{E}_p(X_k):= \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^n \int_{\{0,1\}^n} X_k(x) \mathbb{P}_{\text{Ber}(p)^{\otimes n}} (dx)
$$
this I understand is the definition of the expected value, but the next step is not clear and I would appreciate your help to understand what was done here
$$
...=\frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^n \int_{\{0,1\}^n} X_k(x) \mathbb{P}_{\text{Ber}(p)^{\otimes n}} (dx)=\int_{\{0,1\}} y \mathbb{P}_{\text{Ber}(p)} (dy)
$$
My guess is
$$
\frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^n \int_{\{0,1\}^n} X_k(x) \mathbb{P}_{\text{Ber}(p)^{\otimes n}} (dx) = \frac{1}{n} \cdot n (\int_{\{0,1\}^n} X_k(x) \mathbb{P}_{\text{Ber}(p)^{\otimes n}} (dx)) = \int_{\{0,1\} \times \{0,1\} \times...\times \{0,1\} } x_k \mathbb{P}_{\text{Ber}(p)^{\otimes n}} d(x_1,...,x_n)= \int_{\{0,1\}}\int_{\{0,1\}}...\int_{\{0,1\}} x_k \mathbb{P}_{\text{Ber}(p)} d(x_1)... \mathbb{P}_{\text{Ber}(p)} d(x_n) = \int_{\{0,1\}}x_k \int_{\{0,1\}}...\int_{\{0,1\}} \mathbb{P}_{\text{Ber}(p)} d(x_1)... \mathbb{P}_{\text{Ber}(p)} d(x_n)\mathbb{P}_{\text{Ber}(p)} d(x_k)= \int_{\{0,1\}}x_k \mathbb{P}_{\text{Ber}(p)} d(x_k)
$$
Since
$$
\int_{\{0,1\}} \mathbb{P}_{\text{Ber}(p)} d(x_i) = 1
$$

Is that ok or is there a mistake and if so, could you please correct it?

Comment: Firstly, $\mathbb{P}_{\text{Ber}(p)^{\otimes{n}}}(\cdot)$ is a discrete measure on $\{0, 1\}^n$. What do you get when you write down the mass put by $\mathbb{P}_{\text{Ber}(p)^{\otimes{n}}}(\cdot)$ on some binary string $s \in \{0, 1\}^n$ (this is a "combinatorial" question) ? For example, take $n = 3$, then what is the mass on say $s = (0, 1, 0)$ ?

Comment: Also, for the first integral in the last equation, consider looking at $\int x \mu(dx) \otimes \nu(dy)$, where $\mu, \nu$ are two probability measures on some spaces. $\text{Ber}(p)^{\otimes n}$ is just $\text{Ber}(p) \otimes \cdots \otimes \text{Ber}(p)$. So effectively, $\int X_k \mathbb{P}_{\text{Ber}(p)^{\otimes n}}(dx)$ is just $\int x_k \mu_1(dx_1) \otimes \cdots \mu_k(dx_k) \otimes \cdots \otimes \mu_n(dx_n)$, where in our case, all the $\mu_i$ are $\text{Ber}(p)$.

Comment: I added to my post :)

Comment: Precisely. That does it. I think you understand the reason fine, but I'll still ask to confirm, you could replace that $\dfrac{1}{n}\sum_{k = 1}^{n}$ with $\dfrac{1}{n} \times n$, only because for each $k$, the quantity inside the $\sum$ comes out to be the same right?

Comment: Yes, thank you. They are the same because the sample is i.i.d. binomial. I could have also taken any other $I \in 1,...,n$ instead of k or just a $y$ that has binomial distribution.

Comment: Yes that is correct. :) Happy to help.